# How can a list box disallow duplicate items?

Tags: delphi, listbox

I was looking at http://delphi.about.com/od/tlistbox/a/list-box-onchange-drag-drop.htm 
and I was wondering if it would be possible to add the ability to disallow duplicate items like this, and if so how would I go and do it?

Thanks

-Brad

Comment: Could you please be more specific about what you mean by "like this"? And what aspect of the linked page is relevant to your question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To prevent duplicates in a list box, simply check whether the intended item exists in the list before you add it.

```
function ItemExists(ListBox: TListBox; const Item: string): Boolean;
begin
  Result := ListBox.Items.IndexOf(Item) >= 0;
end;
```

Call that function before you call `Items.Add`. If it returns True, don't call `Items.Add`.

Comment: OMG, It's so simple.. why I didn't see it before!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I often use;

```
var
  item1 : string;
begin
  item1 := Trim(eSym1.Text);
  if ListBox1.Items.IndexOf(item1) < 0 then
    ListBox1.Items.Add(item1);
end;
```

Comment: Please check [how to write an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). 
Add more details to justify your answer.